# Lifetime of an Imgur image

Tags: html, api, imgur, lifetime

Well, I know that if an image is uploaded to Imgur service and is not seen within 6 months, it will be deleted.
Now my question is:
Is it considered as seen when I load the image from its direct URL (e.g: https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4stF.jpg) ? (note the file extension) instead of loading from its /gallery/ URL

PS: I know this question is a little Off-topic, but I think it's related with programming because I'm using the Imgur API.

Comment: I believe this is not a programming-related question per se...

Comment: Yes I know, but I don't know where to ask my question and I think you can know the answer. Maybe you've worked with Imgur before

Comment: I am quite confident the developer behind the site are at a better position to [answer your question](http://help.imgur.com/hc/en-us/requests/new). As far as I know, we do not know for sure how imgur handles old image files, or how images are marked as viewed.

Comment: Thanks. I will ask the Imgur developer

Comment: maby ping sites like [uptimerobot.com](http://uptimerobot.com) help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My reading of their faq is that any view counts.  They are not really a gallery site, so most images will only ever be seen embedded on other sites.  It would be a bit rum of them to delete such images without being clearer about the rule.

However, my answer would be simply "ask them directly if you are worried" - https://imgur.com/contact